# Center UIImageView with PSCollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

In my app I'm using the [PSCollectionView](https://github.com/ptshih/PSCollectionView), in which I want to show a text label and an image. I'm getting crazy about how to center image and text. I tried in this way:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.productImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 100, 75)];
        self.labelName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 80, 100, 20)];
        self.labelName.font = [self.labelName.font fontWithSize:12];
        self.labelName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

        [self addSubview:self.productImage];
        [self addSubview:self.labelName];

        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:236.0f/255.0f green:236.0f/255.0f blue:236.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
        self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
        self.layer.borderColor= [[UIColor colorWithRed:207.0f/255.0f green:207.0f/255.0f blue:207.0f/255.0f alpha:1] CGColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

But the result is this:

[image: Simulator view]

You can see that the text and the image aren't in center, how I can center them? Note the image may can have different size.
Can you help me to find a way to correct the view?

UPDATE:
Here's the `cellForRowMethod`and the method who download the image:

```
- (PSCollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(PSCollectionView *)collectionView cellForRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    ProductViewCell *cell = (ProductViewCell *)[self.psView dequeueReusableViewForClass:nil];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[ProductViewCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 70, 100, 100)];
    }
    cell.labelName.text = [[self.arrayWithData objectAtIndex:index]objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[self.arrayWithData objectAtIndex:index]objectForKey:@"url"]];

    [self loadImageFromWeb:url andImageView:cell.productImage];
    return cell;
}

- (void) loadImageFromWeb:(NSURL *)urlImg andImageView:(UIImageView *)imageView {
    //NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:urlImg];

    NSString *authCredentials =@"user:password";
    NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@",[authCredentials base64EncodedStringWithWrapWidth:0]];
    [request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
                                               NSData * data,
                                               NSError * error) {
                               if (!error){
                                   UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                                   [imageView setImage:image];
                               } else {
                                   NSLog(@"ERRORE: %@", error);
                               }

                           }];
}
```

Comment: Do you use auto layout ?

Comment: It's a custom view I'm not sure about if it use auto layout or not... There's a way to know if I'm using auto layout? There's a way to center image by using the code without storyboard/xib?

Comment: Do you have a xib for your collection view ?

Comment: no, I'm design the view by code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using frames so I assume you do everything from code (not storyboard) so:

```
self.productImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 100, 75)];
self.labelName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 80, 100, 20)];
```

You have different `x` values here.  This may cause you a problem with centre it.

What you should do is read the cell frame and then use it to set content frame. So you should call it from method:

```
- (MyCell *)collectionView:(PSCollectionView *)collectionView cellForRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableViewForClass:[MyCell class]];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[MyCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,collectionView.frame.size.width,50)];
    }
   // here you have to do other stuff, like assigning display text or something like that.
}
```

This will create single row of cells with `50` height. If you want two rows you should implement counter and manipulate with 'x' value.

I don't really know `PSCollectionView`. Why do you need it? The `UICollectionView` is pretty good.

**EDIT:**

Great, so you just have to change this lines in `initWithFrame` in your cell class:
float wMargin = 5;

```
self.productImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(wMargin, 5, frame.size.width-(wMargin*2), 75)];
self.labelName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(wMargin, 80, frame.size.width-(wMargin*2), 20)];
```

If you want to move content from edges you should operate with `wMargin` variable

**EDIT2:**
Hmm strange. Try to change this line in `cellForRowAtIndex`

```
cell = [[ProductViewCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 70, 100, 100)];
```

to:

```
cell = [[ProductViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,collectionView.frame.size.width/2,100)];
```

Comment: I use that view, because I want a view similar to pinterest. I asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19831727/wall-view-controller-ios) some days ago how to do a "wall view" and a people suggest me to use the PSCollection view

Comment: I will use `UICollectionView` and this custom layout https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout. But if you already start with this maybe better for you to stick on that.You paste `initWithFrame` in your question. Fro what class?

Comment: The `initWithFrame` it's on the class that extends `PSCollectionViewCell`. I've to put the label on the bottom bounds of cell with a centered text and the image should be inside this cell and in center

Comment: OK, great. So you should pass a frame from `cellForRowAtIndex`. Please, show this method in your question.

Comment: It doesn't go... I made so: I create a variable `float wMargin = 5.0;`, then I copied your code to my class, but when I try the app on the simulator the image and the label aren't centered

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41025/discussion-between-lucgian841-and-kuba)